# getting error undefined variable for different functions

Tags: php, database, laravel

Hello so i have a page where i call data from database to view it. on that page i have done a search function which is separated as below. but after creating the main function im having error: Undefined variable: db. i do not understand why is it looking for 'db' when the search function is a different function?

my blade file :

```html
<div class="container-fluid container-fixed-lg">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <div class="panel-title">Answer Few Questions</div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">

       

       @foreach($db as $intentName => $questionAnswer)

       <?php
       $number = 0;
       ?>
       
                <div class="form-group edit-response-container">
                  <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-{{$number}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-{{$number}}"> {{$intentName}} <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></label>
                  <div class="collapse" id="collapse-{{$number}}">
                    <div class="well">
         <form action="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\ChatbotController@savedmb', [$companyID, $entityType])}}" method="post">
               {{csrf_field()}}
          <div class="col-md-12 btn-toolbar">
           <button type="button" class="btn alt-btn alt-btn-green pull-right add-new">Add Answer</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn alt-btn alt-btn-green pull-right">Save</button>
          </div>

          @foreach($questionAnswer['q1'] as $question => $questionID)
                     <table class="question">
                       <tr>
                         <td class="labels"><p>User:</p></td>
                         <td><p>&nbsp;{{$question}}</p></td>
                       </tr>
                     </table>
                   @endforeach

                   @foreach($questionAnswer['q2'] as $question => $questionID)
                     <table class="question">
                       <tr>
                         <td class="labels"><p>User:</p></td>
                         <td><p>&nbsp;{{$question}}</p></td>
                       </tr>
                     </table>
                   @endforeach

                   @foreach($questionAnswer['q3'] as $question => $questionID)
                     <table class="question">
                       <tr>
                         <td class="labels"><p>User:</p></td>
                         <td><p>&nbsp;{{$question}}</p></td>
                       </tr>
                     </table>
                   @endforeach
                   <br><br>

          <div class="new-field">
           <table class="response">
            <tr>
             <td class="labels"><p>Answer:</p></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="newAnswer[]" value=""></td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </div>


               </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <?php
        $number++;
       ?>

                @endforeach


      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

mainfunction:

```html
 public function addType($companyID, $entityType)
 {
  $data = [];
  $intentTypes = DiraQuestion::select('intent')->where('company_id', $companyID)->groupBy('intent')->get();

  foreach ($intentTypes as $intent) 
  {
   $data[$intent->intent] = $intent->intent;
  }



  $db = [];
  $dmb = DiraMasterBot::all();
  foreach ($dmb AS $datum) 
  { 
   if (!isset($db[$datum->description])) $db[$datum->description] = ['intent' => [], 'q1' => [], 'q2' => [], 'q3' => []]; 
   $db[$datum->description]['intent'][$datum->intent] = $datum->id; 

   if (!isset($db[$datum->description])) $db[$datum->description] = ['intent' => [], 'q1' => [], 'q2' => [], 'q3' => []]; 
   $db[$datum->description]['q1'][$datum->sampleQ1] = $datum->id; 

   if (!isset($db[$datum->description])) $db[$datum->description] = ['intent' => [], 'q1' => [], 'q2' => [], 'q3' => []]; 
   $db[$datum->description]['q2'][$datum->sampleQ2] = $datum->id; 

   if (!isset($db[$datum->description])) $db[$datum->description] = ['intent' => [], 'q1' => [], 'q2' => [], 'q3' => []]; 
   $db[$datum->description]['q3'][$datum->sampleQ3] = $datum->id; 
  } 

  ksort($db);
  // dd($db);


  return view('AltHr.Chatbot.addType', compact('db','data','entityType','companyID'));
 }
```

search function:

```html
 public function search(Request $request, $companyID, $entityType)
 {
  $data = [];
  $intentTypes = DiraQuestion::select('intent')->where('company_id', $companyID)->groupBy('intent')->get();

  foreach ($intentTypes as $intent) 
  {
   $data[$intent->intent] = $intent->intent;
  }

  $q = $request->q;
     $user = DiraQuestion::select('eVal')->where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->groupBy('eVal')->get();

     return view('AltHr.Chatbot.addType', compact('data','entityType','companyID'))->withDetails($user)->withQuery($q);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're returning the same view which is `'AltHr.Chatbot.addType'`. So in that view file you are using `$db` variable in `foreach` loop. You should either check if `$db` variable is set before `foreach` loop or return another view without `$db` variable.

Comment: how do i set $db before foreach loop?

Comment: You are not gonna set `$db` variable before foreach. You are gonna check if `$db` is set, which means:
`@if(isset($db))`
`@foreach....`
`@endforeach`
`@endif`
But in that case you will get a blank page, because in blade file, you are looping `$db` variable so you need to fill `$db` variable in search function and send it to blade.

P.S: You can use `@php .... @endphp` instead of `<?php ... ?>` in blade files.